# How to check current pm.max_children setting?

Tags: php, php-fpm, php7

I have modified pm.max_children in `/opt/plesk/php/7.0/etc/php-fpm.d/domain.com.conf` file.

I restarted the php70-fpm service and want to check whether my settings are enabled or not.

How can I check this setting?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to know how many workers are currently running, you can try with HTOP, do a htop and filter (F4) with "php-fpm".

Or with ps

```
ps aux | grep "php-fpm: pool"
```

If you want precise and technical informations, you can use the fpm status page:

Add this to you pool configuration:

```
pm.status_path = /status
```

Then this in your nginx configuration: (adapt to your configuration)

```
location ~ ^/(status|ping)$ {
     access_log off;
     allow 127.0.0.1;
     allow 10.10.10.10#your-ip;
     deny all;
     include fastcgi_params;
     fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

You can then use CURL to query with:

```
 curl http://localhost/status
```

Which gives you something like:

```
pool:                 www
process manager:      dynamic
start time:           01/Mar/2019:15:16:10 +0100
start since:          2551
accepted conn:        7843
listen queue:         0
max listen queue:     0
listen queue len:     0
idle processes:       8
active processes:     2
total processes:      10
max active processes: 10
max children reached: 0
```

More informations / Source: https://easyengine.io/tutorials/php/fpm-status-page

Comment: I can only see the currently running php-fpm processes but I can not see what the max value is.

Comment: I edited my answer with a more complete method.

Comment: so the max children value is the number of "max active processes"?

Comment: I think so, yes. Can someone confirm ?

Comment: according to comments in the default php-fpm `.conf` file:
`max active processes - the maximum number of active processes since FPM has started` -- so this answer is incorrect